# What is the equivalent of Pytorch's "detach" in Keras?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, pytorch

"Detach" in Pytorch returns a new Tensor, detached from the current graph. The result will never require gradient.This method also affects forward mode AD gradients and the result will never have forward mode AD gradients.

Is there an equivalent in keras? the idea in freezing the learning of some layers. I've tried "trainable" in Keras, but it seems to have the same functionality. Thanks for the help.